# C++: call static member function on base pointer of different class's derived object

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

**Edit**: The example below does *not* work as thought. For *this* question, [Steve Jessop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13005/steve-jessop)'s answer is correct. A [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059116/) has been created with a corrected example. The question may be deleted depending on the community rules. Or the body may be shortened to "Is it possible to call a static member function (pointer) on the pointer of a base class?" with the example below to match the answer. The *more specifics* (cocos2d-x) section below the example may be removed.

Is it "safe" (and/or portable) to call a static member function (pointer) on the pointer of a base class, but the object is a different derived class.

```
class Base { /* ... */ }
class DerivedA  : public Base {
    /* ... */ 
    static void doSomethingStaticA(float f);
}
class DerivedB  : public Base { /* ... */ }

typedef void (Base::*SEL_SCHEDULE)(float);
SEL_SCHEDULE pCallback = (&DerivedA::doSomethingStaticA);

DerivedB db = new DerivedB();
Base *b = &db;
/* pCallback and b are saved in a list elsewhere (a scheduler) which calls */
b->pCallback(0.f);
```

<s>This *seems to work* (in MSVC/Debug mode) okay, but I'm wondering whether this is Bad (TM) - and why? (I'm yet to test this code with the compilers for Android and iOS).</s>

Some more specifics if required: I'm building a [cocos2d-x](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/) based project. `Base` is [`CCObject`](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/cocos2dx/cocoa/CCObject.h), `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` are subclasses of [`CCLayer`](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/cocos2dx/layers_scenes_transitions_nodes/CCLayer.h).

The hierarchy is `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` < [`CCLayer`](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/cocos2dx/layers_scenes_transitions_nodes/CCLayer.h) < [`CCNode`](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/cocos2dx/base_nodes/CCNode.h) < [`CCObject`](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/cocos2dx/cocoa/CCObject.h).

`DerivedA` has a different static function to set up playback of music which receives a [`CCNode`](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/cocos2dx/base_nodes/CCNode.h) caller object as a parameter and [schedules](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/cocos2dx/base_nodes/CCNode.cpp#L1059) another [selector](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/cocos2dx/cocoa/CCObject.h#L78) (`doSomethingStaticA`) to begin playback and slowly fade it in using something like:

```
callerNode->schedule(schedule_selector(DerivedA::doSomethingStaticA), 0.05f);
```

`doSomethingStaticA` does things such as [such as](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/CocosDenshion/include/SimpleAudioEngine.h#L141)

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->setBackgroundMusicVolume(sFadeMusicVolume);
```

The call to `doSomethingStaticA` at runtime happens in [CCTimer::update](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/cocos2dx/CCScheduler.cpp#L160).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not even be able to initialize `pCallback` with `&DerivedA::doSomethingStaticA`, since a pointer to a static member function is actually a pointer-to-function, not a pointer-to-member-function.

So something is Bad, even if just your example code ;-) Also `b->pCallback` maybe is supposed to be `b->*pCallback`, `new` returns a pointer that can't be used to initialize `db`, there are some missing semi-colons, and maybe other problems I've missed. Write a short program that compiles, post it, and ask your question about that program.